# amcharts property stackable wrong stack

Tags: amcharts

Good evening,

I found an example on Amcharts 2 but I get a weird error with the property "stackable"

It doesn't stack properly if I add the property on different column. I tried differents options but none works. Someone know how to fix it please?

```
 // second graph              
graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.title = "North America";
graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
graph.valueField = "namerica";
graph.type = "column";
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.fillAlphas = 1;
graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
chart.addGraph(graph);

// third graph                              
graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.title = "Asia-Pacific";
graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
graph.valueField = "asia";
graph.type = "column";
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.fillAlphas = 1;
graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
graph.stackable = false;
chart.addGraph(graph);
```

Link : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnWXf/1112/)

Comment: looks ok to me, with charts i always try to just do one chart first then build on that.

Comment: if you click on jsfiddle, you can notice the third graph is not stacked properly on the fourth graph. They are not stacked like on amcharts 3 demo : [link](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-clustered-column-chart/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1) You're using the v2.x version of AmCharts in your demo. You want to use v3.x is under `lib/3/`, i.e. `//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js` and `//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js`.

2) As the demo you linked states below the graph, you need to set [`newStack`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#newStack) to `true` if you want to create a new stack. Setting `stackable` to false won't work.

```
// third graph                              
graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.title = "Asia-Pacific";
graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
graph.valueField = "asia";
graph.type = "column";
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.fillAlphas = 1;
graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
graph.newStack = true; //create new stack
chart.addGraph(graph);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnWXf/1117/)

Comment: My project use v2.x so do you think it is a solution to fix the problem?

Comment: Nope. `newStack` is only in v3. Your code will work just fine without any changes in v3 as it keeps the 2.x API. Just make sure you include the right libs as it's not combined into a single file like in v2.

Comment: Ok I upgraded my project on v3.x and it works good with newStack. It is just shame, it doesn't work with the property stackable on V2.x. Thanks